# Is there any way to create data class instance in other data class in python?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have some questions about using datacalss in python.

I am using data class structure to communicate json object which is created by data class and converted.

I'd like to make a indipendant log count data class for another data class and managing instant of log count at the same time.
Not only for this case, but also all of my communication protocols.

```
@dataclass
class Report:
    @dataclass
    class LogCount:
        critical: int = 0
        error: int = 0
        warning: int = 0
        info: int = 0
        debug: int = 0

    @dataclass
    class Store:
        @dataclass
        class Platform:
            name: str = ""
            sales: int = 0
            settlement: int = 0
            ratio: int = 0
            count: int = 0

        name: str = ""
        sales: int = 0
        settlement: int = 0
        count: int = 0
        platforms: List[Platform] = field(default_factory=list)

    log_count: LogCount = field(default_factory=LogCount)
    notice: str = ""
    stores: List[Store] = field(default_factory=list)


@staticmethod
def todict(dataclass):
    return asdict(dataclass)

@staticmethod
def tojson(dataclass):
    return json.dumps(asdict(dataclass))
```

I'd like to define Log count out side of data class and create instance like this

```
@dataclass
class LogCount:
    critical: int = 0
    error: int = 0
    warning: int = 0
    info: int = 0
    debug: int = 0

@dataclass
class Report:
    @dataclass
    class Store:
        @dataclass
        class Platform:
            name: str = ""
            sales: int = 0
            settlement: int = 0
            ratio: int = 0
            count: int = 0

        name: str = ""
        sales: int = 0
        settlement: int = 0
        count: int = 0
        platforms: List[Platform] = field(default_factory=list)

    log_count: LogCount = field(default_factory=LogCount)
    notice: str = ""
    stores: List[Store] = field(default_factory=list)
```

Can I add data class instance to another data class ?

Comment: Have you tried it?  What happened?  You don't actually need the classes to be defined nested like this.  You should be able to define them as separate classes and include instances.

Comment: Defining a nestesd class is the wrong approach: the inner clsssses won't show up as Fields in the outer classes - it will just be a complete mess.
Maybe you should just use the json structure as dicts and lists?

Comment: more specified code here, nested class is necessary in communication protocol, all the json objects have data key, and I don't want to define every Data classes name differently

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105558/is-there-any-way-to-create-shared-data-class-instance-json-communication-protoco